# react-select: Clear selected value during onChange from another Select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I have 2 select elements in my react functional components as follows:

```
<Select
  options={areaTimeSlots}
  onChange={ (selectedTimeSlotLabel) => handleTimeSlot (selectedTimeSlotLabel) }
  placeholder="Select a delivery slot"
/>
```

and

```
<Select options={areaData} onChange={(value) => handleSelectedArea(value)}  />
```

I want to clear the selected option from areaTimeSlots (select-1) if `onChange` is triggered from select-2 (handleSelectedArea).

I tried like below using react hooks and ref but both are not working

```
const [selectedTimeSlotLabel, setTimeSlotLabel] = useState(null);
const handleSelectedArea = async (e: any) => {
  setTimeSlotLabel(null);
}
 
<Select
  options={areaTimeSlots}
  isClearable={true}
  onChange={ (selectedTimeSlotLabel) => handleTimeSlot (selectedTimeSlotLabel) }
  value={selectedTimeSlotLabel}  placeholder="Select a delivery slot"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the value of the first `Select` and reset it whenever you change the second one:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

return (
  <>
    <Select options={options1} value={value} onChange={setValue} />
    <Select options={options2} onChange={() => setValue(null)} />
  </>
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I already tried this solution but it is not working as expected. Also I would like to highlight that whenever i use value={value} the selected one is not showing as selected. I think my value is not getting populated during select . But without value option in select i can see that selected option is showing as selected value

Comment: Above method will work , My select was expecting a value label pair so i forced to make each of them as null as follows useState([{value:null,label:null}]); Accepting your answer

Comment: @SumithChalil Sorry I was watching football, you're missing some code in the question so I couldn't say what exactly was your problem.